# Simple-Framework: Duplicate annotation (different namespace)

Tags: java, annotations, xml-namespaces, simple-framework, duplicates

I have an Rss feed that I'd like to parse in Java using Simple Framework.
I have problems with 2 elements with the same name, but one of them has a namespace assigned.
Here is an example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <item>
        <title>Regular Titel</title>
        <dc:title>Dc Titel</dc:title>
    </item>
</rss>
```

Currently my Item.class looks like this:

```
@Root
public class Item {

    @Namespace(reference = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", prefix = "dc")
    @Element(name="title")
    public String dcTitle;

    @Element
    public String title;
}
```

This obviously causes a PersistenceException (Duplicate annotation of name 'title' on field 'title'....), but i don't really know how I should do this. Could someone please help me to figure this out!

**UPDATE**

Althought the solution works, I now have problems serializing the objects. The namespaces, that I declare, are not assigned to the elements in the output xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@Root
public class Item {

    @Namespace(reference = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", prefix = "dc")
    @Path("title[1]")
    @Text
    public String dcTitle;

    @Path("title[2]")
    @Text
    public String title;
}
```

Comment: If it works, please **accept** the answer (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask )

Comment: I was i little too hasty. When I serialize the object, the prefix of the namespace is missing.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
@Root
@Namespace(reference = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/", prefix = "dc")
public class Item {

    @Element (name = "dc:title")
    public String dcTitle;

    @Element (name = "title")
    public String title;
}
```